# How to assign a timbre from a wav file to midi using python?

Tags: python, wav, midi

I will try to clearly explain the essence of the issue. Suppose there is a midi file, well, for example, take such a midi, example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAupqV3Mgwk
Piano Synthesia
As you can hear, the timbre of the piano is playing here.

Suppose there is a wav sample with a guitar sound
I uploaded a sample here
https://dropmefiles.com/0Om7X

Is it possible, having a midi file and a sound sample from a wav file, to assign this sound to the tracks of a midi file?
For example, in the case of the melody that I provided above
if  assign a guitar timbre from a wav file, then instead of the piano, the sound of the guitar would play.
Well, I also found an example of such a sound on YouTube, but here man plays.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lKVPJVH0jA
But the question is whether it is possible to take the sound timbre from a wav file and make the midi file play with this timbre selected using python language?

I really hope you understand the question I want to ask.
Thank you

I used audio-to-midi ,but it is not what i need

Answer (score -1):

You just described what MIDI does. If I'm understanding you correctly.
Look at it this way. If you have a MIDI file, you essentially have sheet music. But no instrument. When it comes to MIDI I would more associate timbre with Velocity (how soft or hard you press the key on your midi controller) or changing timbre with layering multiple samples (.WAV .Mp3 or any audio file is a sample) and mapping them to one specific MIDI note. I think you are basically describing a sampler. (sorry if my tone sounds snarky or rude, I'm being very Ernest right now. MIDI is a learning curve.) If you have a sampler in your DAW or physical, what you are doing is mapping your samples (again ANY audio file can be considered a sample) to specific notes on your MIDI controller. You are not changing the timbe tone or anything about that audio file. If you want to map one sample to multiple notes so you can have variation in tone you need to pitch up or down that sample and map that pitched up or down version of the sample to the next note. so simply. MIDI file says "Play these notes: A2 A#2 B2 C3" to your Virtual Instrument (DAW VST or program). your Virtual instrument says ok and plays whatever sound file is mapped to those specific notes. it could be something like (A2 =babycrying.WAV) (A#2=barking.Mp3) (B2=GuitarRiff.wav) (C3=WetFart.AIF) So then imagine all of those audio files played in sequence from start to end and overlapping each other. But Midi Doesn't just give info on the note to be played. It also gives Velocity and gate information and then also note off info. (which Gate and note off are the same.) To play your guitar sample from a midi file you will need to pitch shift the sample. Your sample has Two chords. So for each midi note it will play two chords. Unless you crop the sample. (Shorten it) So just chop stretch squeeze and manipulate that sample in any daw/worksatation/sampler and use at least 12 semitones for one octave and you'll need at least 2-3 octaves. so 36 sample files to create your midi controlled guitar... and map them in python so when python receives the midi data/syntax it knows which one of those 36 samples to play. So it's not a simple answer. I'm on here to learn more about coding I got the midi and music parts down. I'm gonna go ahead and create those samples for you. I will Post the link in just a little while. I got you dog. But I know there is a terminal program or CMD prompt that monitors MIDI in/out data. I need to find that and we can figure out the rest from there. Are you using a physical MIDI Controller? Or just the midi file?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).